# Using the GET parameter of a URL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, get

If I am on a page such as

http://somesite.com/somepage.php?param1=asdf

In the JavaScript of that page, I would like to set a variable to the value of the parameter in the GET part of the URL.

So in JavaScript:

```
<script>
   param1var = ...   // ... would be replaced with the code to get asdf from URI
</script>
```

What would "..." be?

Comment: There are much better answers in the linked question.

Comment: check best ans here without regular expression stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery/… –  Sameer Kazi

Comment: Here's a simple solution :  http://mycodingtricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Here's some **[sample code](http://www.zrinity.com/developers/code_samples/code.cfm/CodeID/59/JavaScript/Get_Query_String_variables_in_JavaScript)** for that.

```
<script>
var param1var = getQueryVariable("param1");

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
  alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should probably call `decodeURIComponent` on `pair[1]` before returning it, and ideally on `pair[0]` before comparing it to variable.

Comment: There is a much neater way these days: `const urlParams = new URL("https://example.com/?product=trousers&color=black&newuser&size=s").searchParams;
const product = urlParams.get('product');
console.log(product);`

Answer (score 12):

You can get the "search" part of the location object - and then parse it out.

```
var matches = /param1=([^&#=]*)/.exec(window.location.search);
var param1 = matches[1];
```

Answer (score 9):

I made this variation of gnarf's solution, so the call and the result is similar to PHP:

```
function S_GET(id){
    var a = new RegExp(id+"=([^&#=]*)");
    return decodeURIComponent(a.exec(window.location.search)[1]);
}
```

But as being called in a function slows the process, its better to use as global:

`window['`*var_name*`'] = decodeURIComponent( /`*var_in_get*`=([^&#=]*)/.exec(window.location.search)[1] );`

**UPDATE**

As I'm still learning JS, I created a better answer in a more JS behaviour:

```
Url = {
    get get(){
        var vars= {};
        if(window.location.search.length!==0)
            window.location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value){
                key=decodeURIComponent(key);
                if(typeof vars[key]==="undefined") {vars[key]= decodeURIComponent(value);}
                else {vars[key]= [].concat(vars[key], decodeURIComponent(value));}
            });
        return vars;
    }
};
```

This allows to be called just using `Url.get`.

*Example*
The url `?param1=param1Value&param2=param2Value`
can be called like:

```
Url.get.param1 //"param1Value"
Url.get.param2 //"param2Value"
```

here is a snipet:

```js
// URL GET params
url = "?a=2&a=3&b=2&a=4";

Url = {
    get get(){
        var vars= {};
        if(url.length!==0)
            url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value){
                key=decodeURIComponent(key);
                if(typeof vars[key]==="undefined") {vars[key]= decodeURIComponent(value);}
                else {vars[key]= [].concat(vars[key], decodeURIComponent(value));}
            });
        return vars;
    }
};

document.querySelector('log').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(Url.get);
```

```html
<log></log>
```

Comment: +1 for being similar to my version (which doesn't use a temp var and encodes the parameter value) and the interesting performance tip in a humorously inappropriate context.

Answer (score 2):

From my programming archive:

```
function querystring(key) {
   var re=new RegExp('(?:\\?|&)'+key+'=(.*?)(?=&|$)','gi');
   var r=[], m;
   while ((m=re.exec(document.location.search)) != null) r[r.length]=m[1];
   return r;
}
```

If the value doesn't exist, an empty array is returned.
If the value exists, an array is return that has one item, the value.
If several values with the name exists, an array containing each value is returned.

Examples:

```
var param1var = querystring("param1")[0];

document.write(querystring("name"));

if (querystring('id')=='42') alert('We apoligize for the inconvenience.');

if (querystring('button').length>0) alert(querystring('info'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it in Coffee Script (just if anyone is interested).

```
decodeURIComponent( v.split( "=" )[1] ) if decodeURIComponent( v.split( "=" )[0] ) == name for v in window.location.search.substring( 1 ).split( "&" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery?  I've used this before:  http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/  and it worked pretty well.

Comment: Unfortunately not (not my choice).

Comment: Original link dead, updated link: https://github.com/allmarkedup/purl

Answer (score 0):

This looked ok:

```
function gup( name ){
   name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
   var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
   var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
   var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
   if( results == null )
      return "";
   else
      return results[1];
}
```

From http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that JSLint likes:

```
/*jslint browser: true */
var GET = {};
(function (input) {
    'use strict';
    if (input.length > 1) {
        var param = input.slice(1).replace(/\+/g, ' ').split('&'),
            plength = param.length,
            tmp,
            p;

        for (p = 0; p < plength; p += 1) {
            tmp = param[p].split('=');
            GET[decodeURIComponent(tmp[0])] = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
        }
    }
}(window.location.search));

window.alert(JSON.stringify(GET));
```

Or if you need support for several values for one key like eg. ?key=value1&key=value2 you can use this:

```
/*jslint browser: true */
var GET = {};
(function (input) {
    'use strict';
    if (input.length > 1) {
        var params = input.slice(1).replace(/\+/g, ' ').split('&'),
            plength = params.length,
            tmp,
            key,
            val,
            obj,
            p;

        for (p = 0; p < plength; p += 1) {
            tmp = params[p].split('=');
            key = decodeURIComponent(tmp[0]);
            val = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
            if (GET.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                obj = GET[key];
                if (obj.constructor === Array) {
                    obj.push(val);
                } else {
                    GET[key] = [obj, val];
                }
            } else {
                GET[key] = val;
            }
        }
    }
}(window.location.search));

window.alert(JSON.stringify(GET));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
function getParmFromUrl(url, parm) {
    var re = new RegExp(".*[?&]" + parm + "=([^&]+)(&|$)");
    var match = url.match(re);
    return(match ? match[1] : "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already running a php page then

php bit:

```
    $json   =   json_encode($_REQUEST, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    print "<script>var getVars = $json;</script>";
```

js bit:

```
    var param1var = getVars.param1var;
```

But for Html pages Jose Basilio's solution looks good to me.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: DON'T DO THIS**
*I decided to leave this here as an example of what you shouldn't do*

You don't need to do anything special, actually. You can mix JavaScript and PHP together to get variables from PHP straight into JavaScript.

```
var param1val = '<?php echo $_GET['param1'] ?>';
```

Comment: This is how XSS attacks occur

Comment: @MeatPopsicle Yeaah I guess I was a bit naïve 7 years ago ;-) If you could downvote it I can leave the answer as an example of what *not* to do