# Get the values from the "GET" parameters (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, url, url-parameters

I have a URL with some GET parameters as follows:

```
www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5
```

I need to get the whole value of `c`. I tried to read the URL, but I got only `m2`. How do I do this using JavaScript?

Comment: Before you post a new answer, consider there are already 50+ answers for this question. Please, make sure that your answer contributes information that is not among existing answers.

Answer (score 2682, accepted):

JavaScript *itself* has nothing built in for handling query string parameters.

Code running in a ([modern](https://caniuse.com/url)) browser  can use the [`URL` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) (a [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API)). `URL` is also implemented by [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#the-whatwg-url-api):

```js
// You can get url_string from window.location.href if you want to work with
// the URL of the current page
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5"; 
var url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("c");
console.log(c);
```

---

For older browsers (including Internet Explorer), you can use [this polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/URL).

You could also use one for [URLSearchParams](https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params) and extract the query string to pass to it with `window.location.search.substring(1)`.

---

You could also use the code from the original version of this answer that predates `URL`. The above polyfill is robust and well tested and I strongly recommend it over this though.

You could access `location.search`, which would give you from the `?` character on to the end of the URL or the start of the fragment identifier (#foo), whichever comes first.

Then you can parse it with this:

```js
function parse_query_string(query) {
  var vars = query.split("&");
  var query_string = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    var key = decodeURIComponent(pair.shift());
    var value = decodeURIComponent(pair.join("="));
    // If first entry with this name
    if (typeof query_string[key] === "undefined") {
      query_string[key] = value;
      // If second entry with this name
    } else if (typeof query_string[key] === "string") {
      var arr = [query_string[key], value];
      query_string[key] = arr;
      // If third or later entry with this name
    } else {
      query_string[key].push(value);
    }
  }
  return query_string;
}

var query_string = "a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5";
var parsed_qs = parse_query_string(query_string);
console.log(parsed_qs.c);
```

You can get the query string from the URL of the current page with:

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var qs = parse_query_string(query);
```

Comment: For older browsers, you may need a [polyfill for `URL`](https://github.com/webcomponents/URL) in addition to the one for `URLSearchParams`. Or you can dodge this issue by replacing the line `var c = url.searchParams.get("c");` in the answer above with `var c = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("c");`.

Comment: Wow, this is extremely useful even in front-end exclusive pages: You could just share a link with parameters and use this code to preload some variables to generate a certain shared view.

Answer (score 269):

Most implementations I've seen miss out URL-decoding the names and the values.

Here's a general utility function that also does proper URL-decoding:

```
function getQueryParams(qs) {
    qs = qs.split('+').join(' ');

    var params = {},
        tokens,
        re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

    while (tokens = re.exec(qs)) {
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    }

    return params;
}

//var query = getQueryParams(document.location.search);
//alert(query.foo);
```

Comment: This code doesn't work. It creates an infinite loop because the regex is compiled in the loop definition which resets the current index.

It works properly if you put the regex into a variable outside of the loop.

Comment: @maxhawkins: It works in some browsers while it would go into an infinite loop in others. You're half-right in that regard. I will fix the code to be cross-browser. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: re = /(\?|\&)([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g; and tokens 2 and 3

Comment: if i use yours i get the first param with URL, example: example.html?a=b&c=d i get example.html?a -> b, c -> d

Comment: @ZiTAL This function is to be used with the query part of a URL, not the entire URL. See the commented-out usage example below.

Comment: Jslint does not like the "insecure" ^ in the regex.

Comment: This works okay but it returns case sensitive params which through me off.

Comment: @Harvey Case insensitivity is not a concern of query parameters. It sounds like an application-specific thing that should be applied along with, or on top of query parameter extraction.

Comment: This also works with base64 tokens which might contain an = char.

Comment: Why `qs.split('+').join(' ');` and not `qs.replace(/\+/g, ' ');` ?

Comment: `qs.split('+').join(' ');` is not necessary, because whitespace code is %20 and it's decoded by decodeURIComponent

Comment: Much  better answer than accepted

Answer (score 261):

[source](https://community.esri.com/thread/33634)

```
function gup( name, url ) {
    if (!url) url = location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( url );
    return results == null ? null : results[1];
}
gup('q', 'hxxp://example.com/?q=abc')
```

Comment: I like this option best, but prefer to return null, or the result, but not an empty string.

Comment: It looks like you have some extra escape chars.  "\\\[" should be "\\[".  Since those are regular strings, the [ and ] don't need to be escaped.

Comment: This is not case insensitive. Where would I add the "i" to make it case insensitive?

Comment: alert(gup('UserID', window.location.href));

Comment: if there is no parameters in the URL, results will be Null and generate an error. testing for null before attempting to parse the array could be better

Comment: use `decodeURIComponent()` on `results[1]` to handle encoded parameter values

Comment: gup = getUrlParameter
:)

Answer (score 250):

This is an easy way to check just one parameter:

Example URL:

```
http://myserver/action?myParam=2
```

Example Javascript:

```js
var myParam = location.search.split('myParam=')[1]
```

if "myParam" exists in the URL... variable myParam will contain "2", otherwise it will be undefined.

Maybe you want a default value, in that case:

```js
var myParam = location.search.split('myParam=')[1] ? location.search.split('myParam=')[1] : 'myDefaultValue';
```

**Update:** This works better:

```js
var url = "http://www.example.com/index.php?myParam=384&login=admin"; // or window.location.href for current url
var captured = /myParam=([^&]+)/.exec(url)[1]; // Value is in [1] ('384' in our case)
var result = captured ? captured : 'myDefaultValue';
```

And it works right even when URL is full of parameters.

Comment: This only works if the parameter you're grabbing is the last one in the URL, which you shouldn't depend on (even if you're only expecting one parameter). e.g. `http://myserver/action?myParam=2&anotherParam=3` would yield not `"2"` but `"2&anotherParam=3"`.

Comment: `(location.search.split('myParam=')[1]||'').split('&')[0]` -- to use with **multiple params** or **possibliy missing** `myParam`.

Comment: or `location.search.split('myParam=').splice(1).join('').split('&')[0]`

Comment: You can gain more precision and allow any order of parameters by prepending with `[?|&]` as in `[?|&]myParam=([^&]+)`

Comment: You may need to decode the value `result = decodeURIComponent(result);`

Comment: When I tried this code it's working but my PC freezing after a while.

Answer (score 160):

Browsers vendors have implemented a native way to do this via URL and URLSearchParams.

```
let url = new URL('http://www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5');
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
console.log(searchParams.get('c'));  // outputs "m2-m3-m4-m5"
```

Currently supported in Firefox, Opera, Safari, Chrome and Edge. For a list of browser support [see here](https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL

https://url.spec.whatwg.org/

Eric Bidelman, an engineer at Google, [recommends](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/01/urlsearchparams) using this [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params) for unsupported browsers.

Comment: According to the MDN link(s) Safari support URL but not URLSearchParams.

Comment: @Markouver Isn't the polyfill take care of that? BTW, Safari is the modern days' IE6

Comment: Why is `new URLSearchParams("www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5").get('a')` returning `null` for me? (On Chrome stable). `b` and `c` seem to work well.

Comment: Updated answer.  My original answer was not properly using URLSearchParams, as it's only designed to work with the querystring portion of the URL.

Comment: What version? Latest?

Comment: Use `url.searchParams` instead `new URLSearchParams(url.search)`.

Comment: @CaioTarifa that property doesnt exist on the window

Comment: Safari has support for it now

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer Edge was just added too! Updated post.

Comment: it fails if I add `#` at the end

Comment: In addition to this, if you are needing to replace any of these params with new values, calling `url.searchparams.set(param, newValue)` with replace the selected existing parameter with the provided `newValue`.

Comment: This is ideal since it decodes URI encoded string values for you.  awesome

Comment: it doesn't seems to return the first param value.

Answer (score 107):

I found this ages ago, very easy:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,    
    function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
  }
```

Then call it like this:

```
var fType = getUrlVars()["type"];
```

Comment: Very nice, it also works using location.search instead of window.location.href

Comment: @pdxbmw It is useless and should be removed. The code may seem clever at first glance, but isn't very well thought out. Improvements: Use `decodeURIComponent()` on value, because that's what you usually want to work with; use `window.location.search` instead of `window.location.href`, because you are only interested in the parameters, not the whole url.

Comment: I used it in my es6 project: 
`decodeURIComponent(window.location.search).replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/g, (m, key, value) => params[key] = value);`

Comment: @Leif suggestion worked great. I was getting in an ID 142# because at the end of the URL was the # generated on a button click. Leaving the function like this `var vars = {};

    window.location.search.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });

    return vars;`

Comment: var parts isn't necessary

Answer (score 83):

You can get the query string in `location.search`, then you can split everything after the question mark:

```
var params = {};

if (location.search) {
    var parts = location.search.substring(1).split('&');

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        var nv = parts[i].split('=');
        if (!nv[0]) continue;
        params[nv[0]] = nv[1] || true;
    }
}

// Now you can get the parameters you want like so:
var abc = params.abc;
```

Comment: What about URL-decoding the parameter names and values?

Comment: This approach doesn't handle arrays. E.g. `?array[]=1&array[]=2` produces `{"array[]": "2"}`, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: @Kafoso There is no clear right or wrong here. First of all, repeated fields with the same names have no specified standard behavior, and is up to the parser to handle. Additionally, the `[]` pattern only has a meaning in some cases (e.g., PHP), but not others. So not "clearly wrong" – just not implemented to handle a non-standard case that you may or may not need to handle.

Answer (score 54):

A super simple way using [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

```
function getParam(param){
  return new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(param);
}
```

It's currently supported in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge, and [others](https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams).

Comment: Get the error: 'SCRIPT5009: 'URLSearchParams' is not defined' when running in Edge.

Comment: @AndreasPresthammer What version of edge?

Comment: @spencer-sm Microsoft Edge 41.16299.820.0

Comment: @iiiml0sto1 What are "prettified URL parameters" ?

Answer (score 39):

I wrote a more simple and elegant solution.

```
var arr = document.URL.match(/room=([0-9]+)/)
var room = arr[1];
```

Comment: Look at that, two lines, does exactly what it says on the tin - and won't break if someone is trying to probe for vulnerabilities and adds a bunch of extra characters and queries unlike a couple of these solutions. Cheers chap!

Comment: This does the job right and only in 2 lines. Great answer!

Comment: I think it would be handy for other a check for null was included. If not, an example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36076822/1945948 (I  had an edit attempt rejected).

Comment: Don't understand... how does this answer the question, which is about getting params from a specific string, 'www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5'?

Comment: Loved this answer, +1'ed. Just a suggestion, you can replace `[0-9] ` for `\d`

Comment: Clever, but what does it say "on the tin", exactly?  Looks to me like it only works if the parameter contains numeric digits, and it can't handle the OP's question, where the parameter is m2-m3-m4-m5??

Comment: it also matches `noroom=1234`, not desirable

Answer (score 34):

Here is a recursive solution that has no regex, and has minimal mutation (only the params object is mutated, which I believe is unavoidable in JS).

**It's awesome because it:**

- Is recursive
- Handles multiple parameters of the same name
- Deals well with malformed parameter strings (missing values, so on)
- Doesn't break if '=' is in the value
- Performs URL decoding
- And lastly, It's awesome because it...argh!!!

**Code:**

```
var get_params = function(search_string) {

  var parse = function(params, pairs) {
    var pair = pairs[0];
    var parts = pair.split('=');
    var key = decodeURIComponent(parts[0]);
    var value = decodeURIComponent(parts.slice(1).join('='));

    // Handle multiple parameters of the same name
    if (typeof params[key] === "undefined") {
      params[key] = value;
    } else {
      params[key] = [].concat(params[key], value);
    }

    return pairs.length == 1 ? params : parse(params, pairs.slice(1))
  }

  // Get rid of leading ?
  return search_string.length == 0 ? {} : parse({}, search_string.substr(1).split('&'));
}

var params = get_params(location.search);

// Finally, to get the param you want
params['c'];
```

Comment: You... you said recursive twice.

Comment: It can't find the first param in the next url :

www.mysite.com?first=1&second=2

Comment: Hi Mario, here is a JSFiddle showing it working with that URL: http://jsfiddle.net/q6xfJ/ - If you have found an error, is this perhaps browser specific? When testing, please note that the answer I supplied uses location.search, which is the '?first=1&second=2' part of the URL. Cheers :)

Comment: I don't see why something is good just because it is recursive.

Comment: Erm, I think you missed the recursion joke there Adam. Although now everyone will miss it because edi9999 removed the second "Is recursive".

Answer (score 32):

I made a function that does this:

```
var getUrlParams = function (url) {
  var params = {};
  (url + '?').split('?')[1].split('&').forEach(function (pair) {
    pair = (pair + '=').split('=').map(decodeURIComponent);
    if (pair[0].length) {
      params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    }
  });
  return params;
};
```

Update 5/26/2017, here is an ES7 implementation (runs with babel preset stage 0, 1, 2, or 3):

```
const getUrlParams = url => `${url}?`.split('?')[1]
  .split('&').reduce((params, pair) =>
    ((key, val) => key ? {...params, [key]: val} : params)
    (...`${pair}=`.split('=').map(decodeURIComponent)), {});
```

Some tests:

```
console.log(getUrlParams('https://google.com/foo?a=1&b=2&c')); // Will log {a: '1', b: '2', c: ''}
console.log(getUrlParams('/foo?a=1&b=2&c')); // Will log {a: '1', b: '2', c: ''}
console.log(getUrlParams('?a=1&b=2&c')); // Will log {a: '1', b: '2', c: ''}
console.log(getUrlParams('https://google.com/')); // Will log {}
console.log(getUrlParams('a=1&b=2&c')); // Will log {}
```

Update 3/26/2018, here is a Typescript implementation:

```
const getUrlParams = (search: string) => `${search}?`
  .split('?')[1]
  .split('&')
  .reduce(
    (params: object, pair: string) => {
      const [key, value] = `${pair}=`
        .split('=')
        .map(decodeURIComponent)

      return key.length > 0 ? { ...params, [key]: value } : params
    },
    {}
  )
```

Update 2/13/2019, here is an updated TypeScript implementation that works with TypeScript 3.

```
interface IParams { [key: string]: string }

const paramReducer = (params: IParams, pair: string): IParams => {
  const [key, value] = `${pair}=`.split('=').map(decodeURIComponent)

  return key.length > 0 ? { ...params, [key]: value } : params
}

const getUrlParams = (search: string): IParams =>
  `${search}?`.split('?')[1].split('&').reduce<IParams>(paramReducer, {})
```

Comment: On a URL without query parameters this will return `Object {"": ""}`

Comment: Looks clean enough to me. The rest of the answers are just too much "magic" without enough explanation.

Comment: This is an awesome answer!

Comment: Thanks @SpencerBigum !

Answer (score 26):

[See this](https://sourceforge.net/p/js-urlparam-omt/wiki/Home/)

```
function getURLParameters(paramName)
{
    var sURL = window.document.URL.toString();
    if (sURL.indexOf("?") > 0)
    {
        var arrParams = sURL.split("?");
        var arrURLParams = arrParams[1].split("&");
        var arrParamNames = new Array(arrURLParams.length);
        var arrParamValues = new Array(arrURLParams.length);

        var i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<arrURLParams.length; i++)
        {
            var sParam =  arrURLParams[i].split("=");
            arrParamNames[i] = sParam[0];
            if (sParam[1] != "")
                arrParamValues[i] = unescape(sParam[1]);
            else
                arrParamValues[i] = "No Value";
        }

        for (i=0; i<arrURLParams.length; i++)
        {
            if (arrParamNames[i] == paramName)
            {
                //alert("Parameter:" + arrParamValues[i]);
                return arrParamValues[i];
            }
        }
        return "No Parameters Found";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

The shortest way:

```
new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("my_key");
```

Comment: I would favor using `new URL(location.href).searchParams.get("my_key")` over `URLSearchParams` since the latter will fail when retrieving the first query parameter of any URL.

Comment: Tested both variants. I agree with you. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 20):

ECMAScript 6 solution:

```
var params = window.location.search
  .substring(1)
  .split("&")
  .map(v => v.split("="))
  .reduce((map, [key, value]) => map.set(key, decodeURIComponent(value)), new Map())
```

Comment: Nice. FYI, because it's a Map, usage is params.get("key");

Comment: I like it but probably it won't get the first param. I created a function based on your example 

`function urlParams(url) {
  const [, searchParams = ''] = url.split('?')
  return searchParams.split('&')
    .map(v => v.split('='))
    .reduce((map, [key = '', value]) => key.length ? map.set(key, decodeURIComponent(value)) : map, new Map())
`}

Answer (score 15):

I use the [parseUri](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/parseuri) library. It allows you to do exactly what you are asking for:

```
var uri = 'www.test.com/t.html&a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5';
var c = uri.queryKey['c'];
// c = 'm2-m3-m4-m5'
```

Answer (score 12):

I use

```
function getVal(str) {
    var v = window.location.search.match(new RegExp('(?:[\?\&]'+str+'=)([^&]+)'));
    return v ? v[1] : null;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Your answer is currently flagged "low quality" and might eventually be removed without.

Comment: I found that if there has a string like '#id'  at the end of the url,and return the last parameter value like 'somevalue#id'

Comment: @Ayano `window.location.search` won't include hash like `#id`.

Comment: @Fancyoung Yes,you are right,i made a mistake that use `location.href`to match the result  instead of the `location.search`.Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my solution. As advised by Andy E while answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript), it's not good for your script's performance if it's repeatedly building various regex strings, running loops etc just to get a single value. So, I've come up with a simpler script that returns all the GET parameters in a single object. You should call it just once, assign the result to a variable and then, at any point in the future, get any value you want from that variable using the appropriate key. Note that it also takes care of URI decoding (i.e things like %20) and replaces + with a space:

```
 function getUrlQueryParams(url) {
  var queryString = url.split("?")[1];
  var keyValuePairs = queryString.split("&");
  var keyValue = [];
  var queryParams = {};
  keyValuePairs.forEach(function(pair) {
    keyValue = pair.split("=");
    queryParams[keyValue[0]] = decodeURIComponent(keyValue[1]).replace(/\+/g, " ");
});
  return queryParams;
}
```

So, here are are a few tests of the script for you to see:

```
// Query parameters with strings only, no special characters.
var currentParams = getUrlQueryParams("example.com/foo?number=zero");
alert(currentParams["number"]); // Gives "zero".

// For the URL you stated above...
var someParams = getUrlQueryParams("www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5 ");
alert(someParams["c"]); // Gives "m2-m3-m4-m5".

// For a query params with URI encoding...
var someParams = getUrlQueryParams("www.example.com/t.html?phrase=a%20long%20shot&location=Silicon+Valley%2C+USA");
alert(someParams["phrase"]); // Gives "a long shot".
alert(someParams["location"]); // Gives "Silicon Valley, USA".
```

Comment: .replace("+", " ") will only replace the first occurrence  You need to use .replace(/\+/g, " ");

Answer (score 10):

this question has too many answers, so i'm adding another one.

```
/**
 * parses and returns URI query parameters 
 * 
 * @param {string} param parm
 * @param {bool?} asArray if true, returns an array instead of a scalar 
 * @returns {Object|Array} 
 */
function getURIParameter(param, asArray) {
    return document.location.search.substring(1).split('&').reduce(function(p,c) {
        var parts = c.split('=', 2).map(function(param) { return decodeURIComponent(param); });
        if(parts.length == 0 || parts[0] != param) return (p instanceof Array) && !asArray ? null : p;
        return asArray ? p.concat(parts.concat(true)[1]) : parts.concat(true)[1];
    }, []);
}
```

usage:

```
getURIParameter("id")  // returns the last id or null if not present
getURIParameter("id", true) // returns an array of all ids
```

this copes with empty parameters (those keys present without `"=value"`), exposure of both a scalar and array-based value retrieval API, as well as proper URI component decoding.

Answer (score 10):

### The easiest way using the `replace()` method:

**From the `urlStr` string:**

```
paramVal = urlStr.replace(/.*param_name=([^&]*).*|(.*)/, '$1');
```

or **from the current *URL*:**

```
paramVal = document.URL.replace(/.*param_name=([^&]*).*|(.*)/, '$1');
```

**Explanation:**

- [`document.URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/URL) - interface returns the document location (page url) as a string.
- [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) - method returns a new string with some or all matches of a *pattern* replaced by a *replacement*.
- `/.*param_name=([^&]*).*/` - the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) pattern enclosed between slashes which means:

  - `.*` - zero or more of any characters,
  - `param_name=` - param name which is serched,
  - `()` - group in regular expression,
  - `[^&]*` - one or more of any characters excluding `&`,
  - `|` - alternation,
  - `$1` - reference to first group in regular expression.

```js
var urlStr = 'www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5';
var c = urlStr.replace(/.*c=([^&]*).*|(.*)/, '$1');
var notExisted = urlStr.replace(/.*not_existed=([^&]*).*|(.*)/, '$1');
console.log(`c === '${c}'`);
console.log(`notExisted === '${notExisted}'`);
```

Comment: Nice solution, but if the parameter is not found, the whole string is returned. I would expect "undefined" in this case.

Comment: Hi @pensan, thank you for your great comment. I just add to the regular expression the handling of the situation when the parameter does not appear in the URL. In this case we get the emty string (not whole string).

Answer (score 8):

Yet another suggestion.

There are some good answers already, but I found them needlessly complex and hard to understand. This is short, simple, and returns a simple associative array with key names corresponding to the token names in the URL.

I added a version with comments below for those who want to learn.

Note this relies on jQuery ($.each) for its loop, which I recommend instead of forEach. I find it simpler to ensure cross-browser compatibility using jQuery across the board rather than plugging in individual fixes to support whichever new functions aren't supported in older browsers.

Edit: After I wrote this I noticed Eric Elliott's answer, which is almost the same, though it uses forEach, while I'm generally against (for reasons stated above).

```
function getTokens(){
    var tokens = [];
    var query = location.search;
    query = query.slice(1);
    query = query.split('&');
    $.each(query, function(i,value){    
        var token = value.split('=');   
        var key = decodeURIComponent(token[0]);     
        var data = decodeURIComponent(token[1]);
        tokens[key] = data;
    });
    return tokens;
}
```

Commented version:

```
function getTokens(){
    var tokens = [];            // new array to hold result
    var query = location.search; // everything from the '?' onward 
    query = query.slice(1);     // remove the first character, which will be the '?' 
    query = query.split('&');   // split via each '&', leaving us an array of something=something strings

    // iterate through each something=something string
    $.each(query, function(i,value){    

        // split the something=something string via '=', creating an array containing the token name and data
        var token = value.split('=');   

        // assign the first array element (the token name) to the 'key' variable
        var key = decodeURIComponent(token[0]);     

        // assign the second array element (the token data) to the 'data' variable
        var data = decodeURIComponent(token[1]);

        tokens[key] = data;     // add an associative key/data pair to our result array, with key names being the URI token names
    });

    return tokens;  // return the array
}
```

For the examples below we'll assume this address:

```
http://www.example.com/page.htm?id=4&name=murray
```

You can assign the URL tokens to your own variable:

```
var tokens = getTokens();
```

Then refer to each URL token by name like this:

```
document.write( tokens['id'] );
```

This would print "4".

You can also simply refer to a a token name from the function directly:

```
document.write( getTokens()['name'] );
```

...which would print "murray".

Answer (score 8):

Or if you don't want to reinvent the URI parsing wheel use [URI.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/)

To get the value of a parameter named foo:

```
new URI((''+document.location)).search(true).foo
```

What that does is

1. Convert document.location to a string (it's an object)
2. Feed that string to URI.js's URI class construtor
3. Invoke the search() function to get the search (query) portion of the url
   (passing true tells it to output an object)
4. Access the foo property on the resulting object to get the value

Here's a fiddle for this.... http://jsfiddle.net/m6tett01/12/

Answer (score 8):

For **Single Parameter Value** like this index.html?msg=1 use following code,

```
$(window).load(function(){
    queryString();
});

function queryString()
{
    var queryString = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var varArray = queryString.split("="); //eg. index.html?msg=1

    var param1 = varArray[0];
    var param2 = varArray[1];

}
```

For **All Parameter** Value use following Code,

```
$(window).load(function(){
    queryString();
});

function queryString()
{
    var queryString = window.location.search;
    var varArray = queryString.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<varArray.length;i++) {
      var param = varArray[i].split("=");
        //parameter-value pair
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here I am posting one example. But it's in jQuery. Hope it will help others:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.url.js"></script>

<!-- URL:  www.example.com/correct/?message=done&year=1990-->

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.url.attr('protocol')  // --> Protocol: "http"
    $.url.attr('path')          // --> host: "www.example.com"
    $.url.attr('query')         // --> path: "/correct/"
    $.url.attr('message')   // --> query: "done"
    $.url.attr('year')      // --> query: "1990"
});
</script>
```

Comment: Copied from your other post: "Requires the url plugin : plugins.jquery.com/url"

Answer (score 8):

I had the need to read a URL GET variable and complete an action based on the url parameter. I searched high and low for a solution and came across this little piece of code. It basically reads the current page url, perform some regular expression on the URL then saves the url parameters in an associative array, which we can easily access.

So as an example if we had the following url with the javascript at the bottom in place.

```
http://TestServer/Pages/NewsArchive.aspx?year=2013&Month=July
```

All we’d need to do to get the parameters id and page are to call this:

**The Code will be:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var first = getUrlVars()["year"];
var second = getUrlVars()["Month"];

alert(first);
alert(second);
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't get why you rolled back my edit of your answer. However you'r welcome to improve it your self :)

Comment: Not working for URL like -> ?action=api_call&dates[]=2022-01-28&dates[]=2022-02-03

Answer (score 7):

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

// Usage for URL: http://my.site.com/location?locationId=53cc272c0364aefcb78756cd&shared=false
var id = getUrlVars()["locationId"];
```

Got from here: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.ru/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

Answer (score 7):

It's the N++ time I am looking for a clean way to do this. 
Will save this here in case I get back cause I know I will...

```js
const parseUrlQuery = (value) => {
  var urlParams = new URL(value).searchParams
  return Array.from(urlParams.keys()).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = urlParams.getAll(key)
    return acc
  }, {})
}

console.log(parseUrlQuery('http://url/path?param1=A&param1=B&param2=ABC&param3=61569'))
```

Answer (score 6):

Simple way

```
function getParams(url){
        var regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,
            params = {},
            match;
        while(match = regex.exec(url)) {
            params[match[1]] = match[2];
        }
        return params;
    }
```

then call it like getParams(url)

Answer (score 6):

**Elegant, functional style solution**

Let's create an object containing URL param names as keys, then we can easily extract the parameter by its name:

```js
// URL: https://example.com/?test=true&orderId=9381  

// Build an object containing key-value pairs
export const queryStringParams = window.location.search
  .split('?')[1]
  .split('&')
  .map(keyValue => keyValue.split('='))
  .reduce<QueryStringParams>((params, [key, value]) => {
    params[key] = value;
    return params;
  }, {});

type QueryStringParams = {
  [key: string]: string;
};


// Return URL parameter called "orderId"
return queryStringParams.orderId;
```

Comment: love this, but didn't work for me without making sure to return the accumulator in the reduce function

Comment: @Ella it was a typo, there is no way it can work without a `return`

Comment: Looks better now, let's hope you make it to the first page!

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I do:

```
var uriParams = getSearchParameters();
alert(uriParams.c);


// background functions:

// Get object/associative array of URL parameters
function getSearchParameters () {
  var prmstr = window.location.search.substr(1);
  return prmstr !== null && prmstr !== "" ? transformToAssocArray(prmstr) : {};
}

// convert parameters from url-style string to associative array
function transformToAssocArray (prmstr) {
  var params = {},
      prmarr = prmstr.split("&");

  for (var i = 0; i < prmarr.length; i++) {
    var tmparr = prmarr[i].split("=");
    params[tmparr[0]] = tmparr[1];
  }
  return params;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// http:localhost:8080/path?param_1=a&param_2=b
var getParamsMap = function () {
    var params = window.location.search.split("&");
    var paramsMap = {};
    params.forEach(function (p) {
        var v = p.split("=");
        paramsMap[v[0]]=decodeURIComponent(v[1]);
    });
    return paramsMap;
};

// -----------------------

console.log(getParamsMap()["param_1"]);  // should log "a"
```

Comment: This returns the first parameter with '?'

Answer (score 5):

[**This Gist by Eldon McGuinness**](https://gist.github.com/EldonMcGuinness/6bccc6a0c62f85c378a6) is by far the most complete implementation of a JavaScript query string parser that I've seen so far.

Unfortunately, it's written as a jQuery plugin.

I rewrote it to vanilla JS and made a few improvements :

```js
function parseQuery(str) {
  var qso = {};
  var qs = (str || document.location.search);
  // Check for an empty querystring
  if (qs == "") {
    return qso;
  }
  // Normalize the querystring
  qs = qs.replace(/(^\?)/, '').replace(/;/g, '&');
  while (qs.indexOf("&&") != -1) {
    qs = qs.replace(/&&/g, '&');
  }
  qs = qs.replace(/([\&]+$)/, '');
  // Break the querystring into parts
  qs = qs.split("&");
  // Build the querystring object
  for (var i = 0; i < qs.length; i++) {
    var qi = qs[i].split("=");
    qi = qi.map(function(n) {
      return decodeURIComponent(n)
    });
    if (typeof qi[1] === "undefined") {
      qi[1] = null;
    }
    if (typeof qso[qi[0]] !== "undefined") {

      // If a key already exists then make this an object
      if (typeof (qso[qi[0]]) == "string") {
        var temp = qso[qi[0]];
        if (qi[1] == "") {
          qi[1] = null;
        }
        qso[qi[0]] = [];
        qso[qi[0]].push(temp);
        qso[qi[0]].push(qi[1]);

      } else if (typeof (qso[qi[0]]) == "object") {
        if (qi[1] == "") {
          qi[1] = null;
        }
        qso[qi[0]].push(qi[1]);
      }
    } else {
      // If no key exists just set it as a string
      if (qi[1] == "") {
        qi[1] = null;
      }
      qso[qi[0]] = qi[1];
    }
  }
  return qso;
}

// DEMO
console.log(parseQuery("?foo=bar&foo=boo&roo=bar;bee=bop;=ghost;=ghost2;&;checkbox%5B%5D=b1;checkbox%5B%5D=b2;dd=;http=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab&http=http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools2.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab"));
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cb57dusv/45/).

Comment: What I don't understand about javascript is why haven't they made and put url parsing functions into a the language itself or at least in a standards library?

low level stuff ilke this shouldn't be reinvented over and over, nor left to developers to utilize whatever entropically variant solutions they will whip up.

If this is solid, then something like this should be made into the standard library.

This is an example of the type of thing in javascript that turns me off to the language.

Answer (score 5):

One liner and IE11 friendly:

```
> (window.location.href).match('c=([^&]*)')[1]
> "m2-m3-m4-m5"
```

Comment: Simplest solution of all.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a short and simple function for getting a single param:

```
function getUrlParam(paramName) {
    var match = window.location.search.match("[?&]" + paramName + "(?:&|$|=([^&]*))");
    return match ? (match[1] ? decodeURIComponent(match[1]) : "") : null;
}
```

The handling of these special cases are consistent with URLSearchParams:

- If the parameter is missing, `null` is returned.
- If the parameter is present but there is no "=" (e.g. "?param"), `""` is returned.

Note! If there is a chance that the parameter name can contain special URL or regex characters (e.g. if it comes from user input) you need to escape it. This can easily be done like this:

```
function getUrlParamWithSpecialName(paramName) {
    return getUrlParam(encodeURIComponent(paramName).replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&"));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
window.location.search.slice(1).split('&').reduce((res, val) => ({...res, [val.split('=')[0]]: val.split('=')[1]}), {})
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add an input box and then ask the user to copy the value into it...it's really easy that way:

```
<h1>Hey User! Can you please copy the value out of the location bar where it says like, &m=2? Thanks! And then, if you could...paste it in the box below and click the Done button?</h1>
<input type='text' id='the-url-value' />
<input type='button' value='This is the Done button. Click here after you do all that other stuff I wrote.' />

<script>
//...read the value on click
```

---

Ok, seriously though...I found this code and it seems to work good:

http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/08/turning-the-querystring-into-a-json-object-using-javascript/

```
function queryToJSON() {
    var pairs = location.search.slice(1).split('&');

    var result = {};
    pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
        pair = pair.split('=');
        result[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1] || '');
    });

    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
}

var query = queryToJSON();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
window.location.href.split("?")
```

then disregard the first index

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(window.location.href.split("?"), 1)
```

returns an array of your url parameters

```
var paramArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(window.location.href.split(/[?=]+/), 1);
var paramObject = paramArray.reduce(function(x, y, i, a){ (i%2==0) ?  (x[y] = a[i+1]) : void 0; return x; }, {});
```

A bit more verbose/hacky but also functional, paramObject contains all parameters mapped as a js object

Answer (score 4):

Here is the [angularJs](https://angularjs.org/) source code for parsing url query parameters into an Object :

```js
function tryDecodeURIComponent(value) {
  try {
    return decodeURIComponent(value);
  } catch (e) {
    // Ignore any invalid uri component
  }
}

function isDefined(value) {return typeof value !== 'undefined';}

function parseKeyValue(keyValue) {
  keyValue = keyValue.replace(/^\?/, '');
  var obj = {}, key_value, key;
  var iter = (keyValue || "").split('&');
  for (var i=0; i<iter.length; i++) {
    var kValue = iter[i];
    if (kValue) {
      key_value = kValue.replace(/\+/g,'%20').split('=');
      key = tryDecodeURIComponent(key_value[0]);
      if (isDefined(key)) {
        var val = isDefined(key_value[1]) ? tryDecodeURIComponent(key_value[1]) : true;
        if (!hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
          obj[key] = val;
        } else if (isArray(obj[key])) {
          obj[key].push(val);
        } else {
          obj[key] = [obj[key],val];
        }
      }
    }
  };
  return obj;
}

alert(JSON.stringify(parseKeyValue('?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5')));
```

You can add this function to `window.location`:

```
window.location.query = function query(arg){
  q = parseKeyValue(this.search);
  if (!isDefined(arg)) {
    return q;
  }      
  if (q.hasOwnProperty(arg)) {
    return q[arg];
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

// assuming you have this url :
// http://www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5

console.log(window.location.query())

// Object {a: "1", b: "3", c: "m2-m3-m4-m5"}

console.log(window.location.query('c'))

// "m2-m3-m4-m5"
```

Answer (score 4):

We can get the **c** parameter values in a simpler way without looping all the parameters, see the below jQuery to get the parameters.

**1. To Get the Parameter value:**

```
var url = "www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5";

url.match(**/(c=)[0-9A-Za-z-]+/ig**)[0].replace('c=',"")
```

(or)

```
url.match(**/(c=)[0-z-]+/ig**)[0].replace('c=',"")
```

returns as a string

> "m2-m3-m4-m5"

**2. To Replace the parameter value:**

```
var url = "www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5";

url.replace(**/(c=)[0-9A-Za-z-]+/ig, "c=m2345"**)
```

Comment: Where is the jQuery. Could you just name it JS if it's JS because there is no jquery.

Answer (score 3):

I like writing shorthand as much as possible:

URL: example.com/mortgage_calc.htm?pmts=120&intr=6.8&prin=10000

Vanilla Javascript:

```
for ( var vObj = {}, i=0, vArr = window.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        i < vArr.length; v = vArr[i++].split('='), vObj[v[0]] = v[1] ){}
// vObj = {pmts: "120", intr: "6.8", prin: "10000"}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function getParamValue(param) {
    var urlParamString = location.search.split(param + "=");
    if (urlParamString.length <= 1) return "";
    else {
        var tmp = urlParamString[1].split("&");
        return tmp[0];
    }
}
```

This should work for your case no matter the param is last or not.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use core javascript to get the param's key value as a js object:

```
var url_string = "http://www.example.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5";
var url = new URL(url_string);
let obj = {};
var c = url.searchParams.forEach((value, key) => {
  obj[key] = value;
});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: The URL object is (a) already mentioned in the accepted answer and (b) is not "core javascript". It is defined in its [own standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#api) and isn't supported by IE.

Answer (score 3):

To extract all url params from search object in window.location as json

```
export const getURLParams = location => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
    const params = {}

    for (let key of searchParams.keys()) {
        params[key] = searchParams.get(key)
    }

    return params
}

console.log(getURLParams({ search: '?query=someting&anotherquery=anotherthing' }))

// --> {query: "someting", anotherquery: "anotherthing"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution I find a little more readable -- but it will require a `.forEach()` shim for < IE8:

```
var getParams = function () {
  var params = {};
  if (location.search) {
    var parts = location.search.slice(1).split('&');

    parts.forEach(function (part) {
      var pair = part.split('=');
      pair[0] = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
      pair[1] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
      params[pair[0]] = (pair[1] !== 'undefined') ?
        pair[1] : true;
    });
  }
  return params;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jskp3/)

The method below returns a dictionary containing the parameters of the given URL. In case there are no paramters it will be null.

```
function getParams(url){
    var paramsStart = url.indexOf('?');
    var params = null;

    //no params available
    if(paramsStart != -1){
        var paramsString = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1, url.length);

        //only '?' available
        if(paramsString != ""){
            var paramsPairs = paramsString.split('&');

            //preparing
            params = {};
            var empty = true;
            var index  = 0;
            var key = "";
            var val = "";

            for(i = 0, len = paramsPairs.length; i < len; i++){
                index = paramsPairs[i].indexOf('=');

                //if assignment symbol found
                if(index != -1){
                    key = paramsPairs[i].substring(0, index);
                    val = paramsPairs[i].substring(index + 1, paramsPairs[i].length);

                    if(key != "" && val != ""){

                        //extend here for decoding, integer parsing, whatever...

                        params[key] = val;

                        if(empty){
                            empty = false;
                        }
                    }                    
                }
            }

            if(empty){
                params = null;
            }
        }
    }

    return params;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use dojo.  No other solution on here is this short or as well-tested:

```
require(["dojo/io-query"], function(ioQuery){
    var uri = "www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5 ";
    var query = uri.substring(uri.indexOf("?") + 1, uri.length);
    var queryObject = ioQuery.queryToObject(query);
    console.log(queryObject.c); //prints m2-m3-m4-m5
});
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP `parse_str` copycat.. :)

```
// Handles also array params well
function parseQueryString(query) {
    var pars = (query != null ? query : "").replace(/&+/g, "&").split('&'),
        par, key, val, re = /^([\w]+)\[(.*)\]/i, ra, ks, ki, i = 0,
        params = {};

    while ((par = pars.shift()) && (par = par.split('=', 2))) {
        key = decodeURIComponent(par[0]);
        // prevent param value going to be "undefined" as string
        val = decodeURIComponent(par[1] || "").replace(/\+/g, " ");
        // check array params
        if (ra = re.exec(key)) {
            ks = ra[1];
            // init array param
            if (!(ks in params)) {
                params[ks] = {};
            }
            // set int key
            ki = (ra[2] != "") ? ra[2] : i++;
            // set array param
            params[ks][ki] = val;
            // go on..
            continue;
        }
        // set param
        params[key] = val;
    }

    return params;
}

var query = 'foo=1&bar=The+bar!%20&arr[]=a0&arr[]=a1&arr[s]=as&isset&arr[]=last';
var params = parseQueryString(query);
console.log(params)
console.log(params.foo)        // 1
console.log(params.bar)        // The bar!
console.log(params.arr[0])     // a0
console.log(params.arr[1])     // a1
console.log(params.arr.s)      // as
console.log(params.arr.none)   // undefined
console.log("isset" in params) // true like: isset($_GET['isset'])



/*
// in php
parse_str('foo=1&bar=The+bar!%20&arr[]=a0&arr[]=a1&arr[s]=as&isset&arr[]=last', $query);
print_r($query);

Array
(
    [foo] => 1
    [bar] => The bar!
    [arr] => Array
        (
            [0] => a0
            [1] => a1
            [s] => as
            [2] => last
        )

    [isset] =>
)*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
url.match(/[?&]c=([^&]*)/)[1]
```

```js
var url = "www.test.com/t.html?a=1&bc=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5";

c= url.match(/[?&]c=([^&]*)/)[1];

console.log(c);
```

This is improvement of Daniel Sokolowski [answer Jun 27 '19](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56793694/860099). Regexp explanation

- `[?&]` first matched character must be `?` or `&` (to omit param like `ac=`)
- `c=` name of parameter with `=` char at end
- `(...)` match in first group
- `[^&]*` zero or more characters ( `*` ) different (`^`) than `&`
- `[1]` choose first group from array of matches

Answer (score 2):

simplified version, tested

```
function get(name){
    var r = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,p={},match;
    while(match = r.exec(window.location)) p[match[1]] = match[2];
    return p[name];
}
```

usage:

var parameter = get['parameter']

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use available resources rather than reinventing how to parse those params.

1. Parse the URL as an object
2. Extract the search params part
3. Transform the searchParams from an Iterator to an Array with array expansion.
4. Reduce the key-value array into an object.

```js
const url = 'http://www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5';
const params = [... new URL(url).searchParams.entries()]
  .reduce((a, c) => Object.assign(a, {[c[0]]:c[1]}), {})

console.log(params);
```

Comment: I've posted an answer that solves the question in a simple and modern way. I'd like to have some feedback if my question is downvoted. Where was I wrong? Is it conceptual or practical? Could it be fixed in the answer? Please, provide feedback!

Answer (score 1):

```
function parseUrl(url){
    let urlParam = url.split("?")[1];
    console.log("---------> URL param : " + urlParam);
    urlParam = urlParam.split("&");
    let urlParamObject = {};
    for(let i=0;i < urlParam.length;i++){
        let tmp = urlParam[i].split("=");
        urlParamObject[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }
    return urlParamObject;
}

let param = parseUrl(url);
param.a // output 10
param.b // output 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Get a single param value:

```
function getQueryParameter(query, parameter) {
return (window.location.href.split(parameter + '=')[1].split('&')[0]);}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by bellow function:

```
function getParameter(parameterName){
        let paramsIndex = document.URL.indexOf("?");
        let params="";
        if(paramsIndex>0)
            params=document.URL.substring(paramsIndex+1, document.URL.length).split("&");
        let result = [];
        for(let i=0;i<params.length;i++)
        {
            console.warn(params[i].split("=")[0].toString()+ "," + params[i].split("=")[1].toString());
            var obj = {"key":params[i].split("=")[0].toString(),"value":params[i].split("=")[1].toString()};
            result.push(obj);
        }
        return passedValue = result.find(x=>x.key==parameterName).value;
    }
```

now you can get parameter value with `getParameter("parameterName")`

Answer (score 0):

Learning from many answers (like [VaMoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20097994/2308745)'s, [Gnarf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/827390/2308745)'s or [Blixt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979996/2308745)'s).

You can create an object (or use the Location object) and add a method that allows you to get the URL parameters, decoded and with JS style:

```
Url = {
    params: undefined,
    get get(){
        if(!this.params){
            var vars = {};
            if(url.length!==0)
                url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value){
                    key=decodeURIComponent(key);
                    if(typeof vars[key]==="undefined") {
                        vars[key]= decodeURIComponent(value);
                    }
                    else {
                        vars[key]= [].concat(vars[key], decodeURIComponent(value));
                    }
                });
            this.params = vars;
        }
        return this.params;
    }
};
```

This allows the method to be called just using `Url.get`.

The first time it will fetch the object from the url, next times it will load the saved ones.

#### *Example*

In a url like `?param1=param1Value&param2=param2Value&param1=param1Value2`, parameters can be fetched like:

```
Url.get.param1 //["param1Value","param1Value2"]
Url.get.param2 //"param2Value"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_GET: function (param) {
    var regex = new RegExp("(?:[?&]+" + param + "=)([^&]*)?", "i");
    var match = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    return match === null ? match : match[1];
}
```

Comment: I have noticed that if you send the parameter with '?' at it's beginning it still understands that its the parameter. was it intended ?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.href) || [null, ''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
}
```

I didn't get any of the other top answers to work.

Comment: This code is very helpful and I still use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a JavaScript tool to do this in one easy step

First, copy this script link into the head of your HTML:

```
<script src="https://booligoosh.github.io/urlParams/urlParams.js"></script>
```

Then simply get the value of `c` using `urlParams.c` or `urlParams['c']`.
Simple!

**[You can see a real demo using your values here](https://booligoosh.github.io/urlParams/index.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5)**.

Also keep in mind that I did develop this, but it's an easy and carefree solution to your problem. This tool also includes hex character decoding, which can often be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you can run this function

```
    function getUrlVars()
    {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }

    var source = getUrlVars()["lm_supplier"];
    var el = source.toString();
    var result= decodeURI(el);

console.log(result)
```

this function get what you want from the url,
var source = getUrlVars()["put what you want to get from the url"];

Answer (score 0):

```
    function gup() {
    var qs = document.location.search;
    qs = qs.split('+').join(' ');
    var params = {}, tokens, re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
    while (tokens = re.exec(qs))
        params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
    return params;
}
```

use it like

```
var params = gup()
```

and then

```
params.param1
params.param2
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the first answer in the latest browser we can use new [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) api,
However a more consistent native javascript easy solution to get all the params in an object and use them could be

#### For Example this class say `locationUtil`

```
const locationSearch = () => window.location.search;
const getParams = () => {
  const usefulSearch = locationSearch().replace('?', '');
  const params = {};
  usefulSearch.split('&').map(p => {
    const searchParam = p.split('=');
    const [key, value] = searchParam;
    params[key] = value;
    return params;
  });
  return params;
};

export const searchParams = getParams();
```

#### Usage :: Now you can import searchParams object in your class

for Example for url --- `https://www.google.com?key1=https://www.linkedin.com/in/spiara/&valid=true`

```
import { searchParams } from '../somewhere/locationUtil';

const {key1, valid} = searchParams;
if(valid) {
 console.log("Do Something");
 window.location.href = key1;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case ( redirect to new domain with all sub url )::

```
window.location.replace("https://newdomain.com" + window.location.pathname);
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried a lot of different ways, but this tried and true regex function works for me when I am looking for param values in a URL, hope this helps:

```js
        var text = 'www.test.com/t.html?a=1&b=3&c=m2-m3-m4-m5'

        function QueryString(item, text){
            var foundString = text.match(new RegExp("[\?\&]" + item + "=([^\&]*)(\&?)","i"));
            return foundString ? foundString[1] : foundString;
        }

        console.log(QueryString('c', text));
```

use like `QueuryString('param_name', url)` and will return the value

> m2-m3-m4-m5

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```
/**
 * get object with params from query of url
 */
const getParams = (url) => {
  const params = {};
  const parser = document.createElement('a');
  parser.href = url;
  const query = parser.search.substring(1);
  if (query !== '') {
    const vars = query.split('&');
    for (let i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
      const pair = vars[i].split('=');
      const key = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]).replace('[]', '');
      const value = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
      
      if (key in params) {
        if (Array.isArray(params[key])) {
          params[key].push(value);
        } else {
          params[key] = [params[key]];
          params[key].push(value);
        }
      } else params[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return params;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I have had the same problem over and over again. 
Now many users here now I'm famous for my HAX work,

so I solve it by using:

PHP:

```
echo "<p style="display:none" id=\"hidden-GET\">".$_GET['id']."</p>";
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("hidden-GET").innerHTML;
```

Simple HAX but working.

Comment: **Danger**: This features a [reflected XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting#Reflected_(non-persistent)) vulnerability.

Comment: You can prevent the XSS by using `htmlspecialchars($_GET['id'])` instead.