# How to extract a GET parameter from the URL in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use the get parameter of the url in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827368/use-the-get-parameter-of-the-url-in-javascript)

Suppose I have this url:

```
s = 'http://mydomain.com/?q=microsoft&p=next'
```

In this case, how do I extract "microsoft" from the string?
I know that in python, it would be:

```
new_s = s[s.find('?q=')+len('?q='):s.find('&',s.find('?q='))]
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the parseUri library available here:
http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/

It allows you to do exactly what you are asking for:

```
var uri = 'http://mydomain.com/?q=microsoft&p=next';
var q = uri.queryKey['q'];
// q = 'microsoft'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(function(){

    var url = 'http://mydomain.com/?q=microsoft&p=next'
    var s = url.search.substring(1).split('&');

    if(!s.length) return;

    window.GET = {};

    for(var i  = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

        var parts = s[i].split('=');

        GET[unescape(parts[0])] = unescape(parts[1]);

    }

}())
```

Think this will work..

Comment: `decodeURIComponent`. `escape`/`unescape` is almost always a mistake.

Comment: Also, this will NOT work with url being a string. Since it uses the method search, I suppose url should be window.location. Apart from these two issues, seems to work fine and importing a library to this task is surely an overkill.