# Get URL parameters and insert into form action url with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an html page that people access using an affiliate link, so it has affiliate code in the url (http://www.site.com?cmpid=1234&aid=123). I want to add the cmpid and the aid to the form action url (so when submitted, it submits to the url /form.aspx but adds the cmpid and aid to the end, ie: form.aspx?cmpid=1234&aid=123).

I have no other option than javascript. I can't make this page php or aspx.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827368/use-the-get-paramater-of-the-url-in-javascript

Comment: I don't think this should be closed.  That question you linked to shows how to get the query strings, but it does not show how to append it to the `<form>` action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.onload = function() {
  var frm = document.forms[0];
  frm.action = frm.action + location.search;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the query string by `location.search`.  Then you should be able to append it onto the form's action directly, something like the following:

```
// Get a reference to the form however, such as document.getElementById
var form = ...;

// Get the query string, stripping off the question mark (not strictly necessary
// as it gets added back on below but makes manipulation much easier)
var query = location.search.substring(1);

// Highly recommended that you validate parameters for sanity before blindly appending

// Now append them
var existingAction = form.getAttribute("action");
form.setAttribute("action", existingAction + '?' + query);
```

By the way, I've found that modifying the query string of the form's action directly can be hit-and-miss - I think in particular, IE will trim off any query if you're POSTing the results.  (This was a while ago and I can't remember the *exact* combination of factors, but suffice to say it's not a great idea).

Thus you *may* want to do this by dynamically creating child elements of the `<form>` that are hidden inputs, to encode the desired name-value pairs from the query.