# How to populate a form from form data stored in localStorage?

Tags: html, forms, validation, jquery-mobile

So I have this js file to store form data in local storage:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() { // dom ready handler for jQuery Mobile

    $('#form1').validate({ // initialize form 1
        // rules
    });

    $('#gotoStep2').on('click', function() { // go to step 2
        if ($('#form1').valid()) {
            // code to reveal step 2 and hide step 1
        }
    });

    $('#form2').validate({ // initialize form 2
        // rules
    });

    $('#gotoStep3').on('click', function() { // go to step 3
        if ($('#form2').valid()) {
            // code to reveal step 3 and hide step 2
        }
    });

    $('#form3').validate({ initialize form 3
        // rules,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
           // serialize and join data for all forms
           var data = $('#form1').serialize() + '&' + $('#form2').serialize() + '&' + $(form).serialize();
           window.localStorage.setItem('formData',data);
           // ajax submit
           return false; // block regular form submit action
        }
    });

    // there is no third click handler since the plugin takes care of this 
    // with the built-in submitHandler callback function on the last form.

});
```

It does the job, but I have no idea how to retrieve that information back to prepopulate the form if the user enters to the site to verify if the data is correct in their respective fields. I know how to do it if the fields are stored individually but I don't know how to do it if it's serialize like the example.

A working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ch32k0/HUNPp/) made by Sparky, I just added `window.localStorage(...)`

BTW: There're over 100 fields not just 3 as in the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a method that get JSON from the URL and I modified to meet the localStorage criteria.

The original function from Jan Turoň in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/how-do-i-parse-a-url-query-parameters-in-javascript):

```
    function getJsonFromUrl() {
  var query = location.search.substr(1);
  var data = query.split("&");
  var result = {};
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i].split("=");
    result[item[0]] = item[1];
  }
  return result;
}
```

And this is the modified version:

```
function getFormFromLocalStorage(station,set,container) {
  var query = ls.getItem(station+set+container); 
  var data = query.split("&");
  var result = {};
  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var item = data[i].split("="); 
    $('#'+item[0]).val(item[1]);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The output for this function is an array, and in my case will fill out the form automatically with previous input submitted in the forms.

Hope this help anybody.