# How to extract a REGEX query string result array into a Javascript object

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the result of a regex match to extract an array of query string values resulting in this:

`["?firstkey=55555", "&secondKey=Words%That%MayBeEscaped", "&thirdKey=http%3A%2F%2Fs7d9.scene7.com%2Fis%2Fimag…x130%3Fwid%3D322%26layer%3Dcomp%26resMode%3Dsharp"]`

What is the proper regex combo to pass into a forEach loop that will create an object of the type:

`{firstKey: "55555", secondKey: "Words%That%MayBeEscaped", thirdkey: "http%3A%2F%2Fs7d9.scene7.com%2Fis%2Fimag…x130%3Fwid%3D322%26layer%3Dcomp%26resMode%3Dsharp"}`

Comment: Please have a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/how-do-i-parse-a-url-query-parameters-in-javascript).

Comment: Thank you @AWolf! That second, underrated answer solved it, and gets my vote as much cleaner:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/how-do-i-parse-a-url-query-parameters-in-javascript/8486146#8486146