# How to get statistics of where visitors come from via URL params

Tags: google-analytics, magento-1.9

There are many QR codes that contains URL of website such as:(it just demos link)

http://www.popupstore.com/index.php?qrcode_type=magazine&location=Singapore
 http://www.popupstore.com/index.php?qrcode_type=banner&location=Vietnam

I need a way can summary to know that where customer come from (nearly same as source/channel in Google Analytics):

- Type: Mazazine, banner, etc.
- Location: Vietnam, Singapore, etc.

Can anyone help me please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create two Custom Dimensions, each for `Type` and another for `Country`

As per your need define the appropriate `Scope` of the dimension, a `Hit` level or `Session` level scope would be appropriate.

You need to push custom dimensions into Google Analytics i.e. additonal JS code in your site.

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':  'Magzine',
   'dimension2':  'Singapore'
});
```

**How this works**

- User scans the code and visits the store
- Site has a JS code snippet that would get the query parameters from the URL and sets a custom dimension for each parameter
- Setting the custom dimension would let Google Analytics know the value of the `Type` and `Country`

It is your JS code that tells Google Analytics what value to take for custom dimension. Google Analytics would not know that the value came from the URL.

To get a query parameter value via javascript you can [refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/how-do-i-parse-a-url-query-parameters-in-javascript), If  you take the function provided there by Jan Turon (head over and give him an upvote of this helps you):

```
function getJsonFromUrl() {
  var query = location.search.substr(1);
  var result = {};
  query.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
    var item = part.split("=");
    result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
  });
  return result;
}
```

You can use this to dynamically set the dimensions based on the url. You first call the function to return an JSON object that has the key/value pairs from the query parameters, then you insert the needed values to set the dimensions:

```
 result = getJsonFromUrl();
 ga('send', 'pageview', {
      'dimension1':  result.qrcode_type,
      'dimension2':  result.location
    });
```

Comment: I tried to add custom dimension but I don't know how Google Analytics can       understand my dimension appropriate with URL parameters ?

Comment: It is your JS code that tells Google Analytics what value to take for custom dimension. Google Analytics would not know that the value came from the URL.

Comment: @SudhirMishra, I took the liberty of editing your answer to include a way of reading the query parameters by javascript. Also I don't think it's a good idea to do a pageview call for each dimension (since this would double the  number of pageviews) so I changed that a bit, too.