# Javascript : For loop from URL parameters

Tags: javascript, for-loop

In my URL I have several parameters I want to use.
For One parameter I have several values.

Now I'm just creating it all manual, but there will be more params to be taken over.
How can I make this future proof?

URL example:

```
  https://www.domain.be/?address%5B0%5D=Gent&tax%5Bprofiel%5D%5B0%5D=387&tax%5Bprofiel%5D%5B1%5D=388&tax%5Bprofiel%5D%5B2%5D=389&distance=40&units=metric&paged=1&per_page=9&lat=51.054342&lng=3.717424&form=1&action=fs
```

How I take the value from the URL ( not my code )

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

```
  var vacature = getUrlParameter('tax[profiel][0]');
  var vacature2 = getUrlParameter('tax[profiel][1]');
```

```
    if (vacature != null) {
    
       if (vacature == '367'){ vacature = "HVAC";}
       else if (vacature == '711'){ vacature = "Handlanger";}
    }
    
    if (vacature2 != null) {
        if (vacature2 == '367'){ vacature2 = "HVAC";}
        else if (vacature2 == '711'){ vacature2 = "Handlanger";}
    }
```

```
 var type = vacature + " " + vacature2;
      document.getElementById('vacature').value = type;
```

I tried starting with a for loop:

```
  var myStringArray = getUrlParameter('tax[profiel]');
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
 var vacature[i] = getUrlParameter('tax[profiel][i]');
    console.log(myStringArray[i]);
}
```

But I guess JS doesn't get the Array and I need to put it into one first?
Maybe with the push() method?

```
  var Array = [];
var arrayLength = --- don't know how to get the amount of vars in url ---;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
Array.push(getUrlParameter('tax[profiel][i]');
}
```

For the next part I think the same arrayLength can be used.

```
for (var iParam = 0; iParam < arrayLength; iParam++) {
    if (vacature[iParam] != null) {
    
       if (vacature[iParam] == '367'){ vacature[iParam] = "HVAC";}
       else if (vacature[iParam] == '711'){ vacature[iParam] = "Handlanger";}
    }
}
```

Is this way of thinking worth something? ^_^
Please give me a nudge in the right way!

much obliged!

Comment: How does your URL query string look like, update the question

Comment: I feel like you're so close to getting there yourself

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I Updated it with the URL

Comment: Try with this - `[...new URLSearchParams('address%5B0%5D=Gent&tax%5Bprofiel%5D%5B0%5D=387&tax%5Bprofiel%5D%5B1%5D=388&tax%5Bprofiel%5D%5B2%5D=389&distance=40&units=metric&paged=1&per_page=9&lat=51.054342&lng=3.717424&form=1&action=fs')]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get array from url with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155462/get-array-from-url-with-javascript)