# How to get url parameters with same name from URL in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example I have this url
`https://www.test.com/test.html?categoryid=4&test1=12&test2=65&brand[0]=val1&brand[1]=val2&test3=15`

Now how do I get value of `brand[0]=val1&brand[1]=val2` but it can be any number of there in the url maybe `brand[2],brand[3] etc...` or none url can be without this parameter

I need to get if brand parameter is in url and if yes then I need to get all which are availabe in the url

Any help would be great!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get array from url with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32155462/get-array-from-url-with-javascript)

Comment: No it works if I had `brand[]=val1&brand[]=val2` but I have `brand[0]=val1&brand[2]=val2`

Answer (score 0):

So you don't really know if there would be parameters or not so that's why I can propose this solution right here it will parse all your parameters anyways and stack them in the `config` JSON in case there is no parameters config would be empty then on your `DOMloaded` event you can handle the cases as you want

```
const config = {};
const loadConfig = () => {
  const urlQuery = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  urlQuery.forEach((e, k) => {
    config[k] = e;
  });
};
const onLoadEvent = () => {
console.log(config) // should contain all the query string params.
}
```

Comment: I think this will give me all the params right? I only need to get `brand` like for this example brand[0] and brand[1]

Comment: right, please test it and let me know how it looks!

Comment: It will give me this - https://prnt.sc/6P_4PfsdGafu but I only need brand param