# Use javascript to capture query entered by user on the URL

Tags: javascript, query-string

I'm working on a project where the user would like to be able to add either "?2yr" or "?4yr" to the end of the URL, but when the user then clicks to another page pass that query along as well.

For example, http://example.com/index.html?2yr is the home page, but when you click say contact it would be http://example.com/powerful_predictors.html?2yr.

I've tried doing the following:

```
var _url = window.location;


if(window.location.href.indexOf("2yr") >- 1) {
    console.log("your url contains the 2yr");

} else if(window.location.href.indexOf("4yr") >-1){ 
    console.log("your url contains 4yr");
}
```

How might I add the "?2yr" or "?4yr" when the user clicks a URL to go to another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through all your anchor tags, and modify the property `href` to add the querystring:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a[href]'), function(el, i) {
    el.href = el.href + location.search;
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Buzinas,

I tried your code but it did not append the URL to include the query string.

Comment: @kirdua sorry, it was a typo. I've fixed my answer. Take a look at the [pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DTxVP7NgJKm708m6yVMc?p=preview) I've created for you.

Comment: thanks. Is there a way for the query string to be added via the address bar. My client wants to just add "?2yr" or "?4yr" through the address bar and that would then get passed to all other hrefs.

Comment: The code in answer will already do that! Try to open [this link](http://run.plnkr.co/ESdRVGYPlDf0NUzN/page.html?4yr), and then change the address bar to `?2yr` and see what happens to the links. :)

Comment: But if you want to show the links in the status bar, you should change the `href` attribute, instead of the property, e.g: `el.setAttribute('href', el.getAttribute('href') + location.search);`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions to the issue, but first, I'd recommend a better parameter parser for your JavaScript code.

[This is a much more robust solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/how-do-i-parse-a-url-query-parameters-in-javascript)

That in place, you have two solutions.

One is to, on page start, run a loop and update all of the `a#href` properties with the HTML parameters you retrieved earlier.  This works, if you are serving static content.  If you have any dynamic content, it quickly falls apart.

So, the next solution is to set up a `delegated event` -- basically, you attach a `click` event to the `body` element, then check what the actual element to be clicked on was.

[You can learn more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Comment: Hi Jeremy, 

I'm already adding certain elements dynamically. As of now one of my buttons is set up as

//URL FOR STUDENT COUNT
var studentCount = "<a href='students_list.html'><span><b>"+data[i].activestudents+"</b> of " + data[i].totalstudents + " Active Students</span></a><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i>";

$(".student-counts").append(studentCount);

I thought of doing, 

var studentCount = "<a href='students_list.html" + _url +"'><span><b>"+data[i].activestudents+"</b> of " + data[i].totalstudents + " Active Students</span></a><i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i>";