# using $location.search on external link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

i try to simply modify a link parameter.

with $location.search() the manipulation of the apps URL is really simple. 
is there a way to use $location.search() for external links too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/how-do-i-parse-a-url-query-parameters-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible. You can use [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/), which has similar helper methods.