# Angular 2 query params from url, not in the address bar

Tags: angular, url

How can I get the query params from a url say, `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xnjw0SBKDM0` using angular 2? I know how to get query params from the `ActivatedRoute` method, but i only need to pass a string, not my current router route.

Comment: Do you mean you'd want to get the value of the "watch" parameter?

Comment: Yes but in general, if I had say 5 parameters, how can I get a dictionary of those key value pairs?

Comment: I don't think Angular has native functionality for parsing user-defined strings into params. You may need to just manually split the URL at `?`, `&` and `=`

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/how-do-i-parse-a-url-query-parameters-in-javascript). This is the method you'd need.

```
function getJsonFromUrl(hashBased) {
  var query;
  if(hashBased) {
    var pos = location.href.indexOf("?");
    if(pos==-1) return [];
    query = location.href.substr(pos+1);
  } else {
    query = location.search.substr(1);
  }
  var result = {};
  query.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
    if(!part) return;
    part = part.split("+").join(" "); // replace every + with space, regexp-free version
    var eq = part.indexOf("=");
    var key = eq>-1 ? part.substr(0,eq) : part;
    var val = eq>-1 ? decodeURIComponent(part.substr(eq+1)) : "";
    var from = key.indexOf("[");
    if(from==-1) result[decodeURIComponent(key)] = val;
    else {
      var to = key.indexOf("]",from);
      var index = decodeURIComponent(key.substring(from+1,to));
      key = decodeURIComponent(key.substring(0,from));
      if(!result[key]) result[key] = [];
      if(!index) result[key].push(val);
      else result[key][index] = val;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I need to get the Params from a string, not my activated route

Comment: Oh. thats not really specific to angular. I can update my answer though.

Comment: Updated my answer. Check out the other answer, it should do what you want. I pasted the relevant code.

Comment: Great I'll try that out