# How to retrieve POST data in NodeJS that was passed using CURL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to pass some parameters to my localhost (which is using nodejs) with a CURL command, but my localhost isn't reading them correctly.

I am doing my POST request to my localhost like this:

```
curl --data "db_name=auto&old_db=Lab.tar.gz&new_db=627999E00_10.tgz" 
     --noproxy localhost 
     -H "Accept: text/plain" 
     -H "Content-Type: text/plain" 
     -X POST http://localhost:8084/auto
```

And I try to retrieve my data params with node like this:

```
app.post('/auto',function(req,res){
    var db_name=req.body.db_name; //undefined
    var old_db=req.body.old_db; //undefined
    var new_db=req.body.new_db; //undefined
    ...
});
```

But `db_name`,`old_db`,`new_db` are all always **`undefined`**.

Also, `req.body` is an empty object `{}`

And `req.url` is just `/auto`

How to I retrieve the parameters that I passed with my curl program in node?

==================
Versions

- NodeJS v6.5.0
- ExpressJS v3.14.0
- CURL v7.22.0

==================
Updates

My ExpressJs configuration is the following:

```
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(_path.join(__dirname, '..', 'Client')));
```

Also I tried some other curl variations:

```
curl --noproxy localhost 
     -H "Accept: text/plain" 
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
     -X POST 
     -d "{'db_name':'auto','old_db':'Lab.tar.gz','new_db':'627999E00_10.tgz'}" 
     http://localhost:8084/auto
```

Comment: Does putting `app.use(express.bodyParser());` in the beginning do anything?

Comment: @J.Chen I already had that :/ I'll add that info to the question

Comment: What about `app.use(express.urlencoded());`?

Comment: i don't know how to read the data in node, but the data is in the POST body, encoded in the application/x-www-urlencoded format. if you find the request body, see here for parsing it https://stackoverflow.com/a/8486188/1067003

Comment: @J.Chen I just added `app.use(express.urlencoded());` and it didn't make a difference :( Also @hanshenrik I'm trying to find `application/x-www-urlencoded` in the POST body but `req.body` is an empty object `{}`

Comment: Hm not sure where to go from here :/ Does it make any difference if you format payload as object rather than querystring?

Comment: @J.Chen Didn't make a difference :'( thank you for helping me debug, I think I'm not reading it correctly in nodejs or something... I'm trying to find where my missing parameters are hiding

Comment: @J.Chen I got it to work now! You were right, the object method helped! I removed the two `-H` options in the CURL command, and changed it to JSON form, then parsed the JSON on the server side! Works now, thank you so much ^-^

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it to work with the help from @J.Chen and @hanshenrik !

If I change the format of the `--data` in my CURL request to be a **JSON object** (like `{'key':'value',...}`) instead of a string (`key=value&...`),

AND if I ***remove*** the `-H "Accept: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: application/json"` from the CURL request,

Then my nodeJS Application finally sees the parameters in `req.body`.

So my final code is:

```
curl --noproxy localhost 
     -X POST 
     -d "{'db_name':'auto','old_db':'Lab.tar.gz','new_db':'627999E00_10.tgz'}" 
     http://localhost:8084/auto
```

And my NodeJS code is:

```
app.post('/auto',function(req,res){
    var parseMe = Object.keys(req.body)[0];
    var parsedParams = JSON.parse(parseMe);

    var db_name=parsedParams.db_name; 
    var old_db=parsedParams.old_db; 
    var new_db=parsedParams.new_db; 
    ...
});
```

Comment: This is quite old, but hopeful it helps: I had to change the quotes: This did not:`data="{'content':'2022'}"`, but this did it: `data='{"content":"2022"}'`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the json body parser middleware

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: btw i think express.bodyParser is deprecated

Comment: Sorry, I already ad this line in there. Turns out it was my CURL command which was the problem! Thank you though!