# Retreiving posted data in an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I just wanted to keep an "Ajax Log" on my application. What do I mean? Having a way to store all the "Internal Server Error" of AJAX requests.
Plus, having to change *all* the `$.ajax` calls would not be useful (if I change the storage system or the error type etc... I shall change all occurences).

So that's what I've got for now :
I made a global AJAX Event function simply with that instruction : `$(document).ajaxError(sendErrorAjax);`
And that's what my `sendErrorAjax` function might look like :

```
function sendErrorAjax( event, response, settings )
{
    let message = 'Error on URL [' + settings.url + '] - Error ' + response.status + ' : ' + response.statusText;
    addToLogs(message);
}
```

And that works fine!
But I'd like to have more precise informations : What about retreiving the data that was sent (client side, not the server side)?

Is there any way to get them?

Comment: Isn't it in `settings.data`?

Comment: Oh... Yeah, that's a good answer in most cases (POST, PUT, DELETE, etc...). Just realise I was using a GET method.   
So I have to parse the URL in my case. In other cases, we can access them by the `settings.data` property, yes. 
  
So in either case, we get a string with all parameters [that we can then parse to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8486188/9863298).