# Show the user's location on a Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I am building a site with Leaflet.js and OpenStreet maps to make a site with many map datapoints. I have been trying to get the map center Lat, Lng, and Zoom into the URL so that users can share their location or go back to where they were viewing previously.

I have scoured the Leaflet docs but so far have not found anything that would help me.

Any assistance would be most appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: That's because this is a basic JavaScript question, not a leaflet question. The leaflet docs assume that you already know js. Use the info from the dupe I linked and pass the data to the map constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse a URL query parameters, in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/how-do-i-parse-a-url-query-parameters-in-javascript)