# Change query parameters of URL using dynamic parameter and value in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, query-string

I need to change the value of query parameters of the given URL irrespective of value type.

I have a function like,

```
function urlGenerator (key, value) {
    var url = "www.domain.com/?id=10&name=xxx&dob=2018-12-13";
    // change the value for given key
    return url;
}
```

The order of query parameters are not fixed. It may be of any order. I think the solution can be found by Regex.

I need generic solution irrespective of the type of value given to above specified URL. I need to call the above method like following and must get the resultant URL.

```
result = urlGenerator('id', 15);
result = urlGenerator('name', 'yyy');
result = urlGenerator('dob', '2018-10-20');
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You would need to parse the url to get an object with all parameters, add / change the value you need to change and rebuild the url. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/how-do-i-parse-a-url-query-parameters-in-javascript for the first step.

Comment: why is there a `php` tag here?

Comment: @mickmackusa While adding regex tag, SO suggested to add the language.

Comment: javascript is a language  ...and happens to be the one that you are using.

Comment: The url is static in your function?

Comment: @MickaelLeger Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it like this**

So here in temp variable we are building a expression for regex using `string template` and than using `RegExp` change it to regex object.And then by using `replace` method we replace the `matched value` with the `value supplied in function`.

```js
function urlGenerator (key, value) {
    let temp = '(?<='+`${key}`+'=)[^&]+'
    let reg = new RegExp(temp,'g');
    console.log(reg);
    var url = "www.domain.com/?id=10&name=xxx&dob=2018-12-13";
    // change the value for given key
    return url.replace(reg, value);
}

result = urlGenerator('id', 15);
console.log(result);
result = urlGenerator('name', 'yyy');
console.log(result);
result = urlGenerator('dob', '2018-10-20');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: @VinothKumar always happy to help :)

Comment: @Jouby I have tried your 1st solution but that doesn't work as expected. Before your edited answer, this answer is posted and it works fine. That's why I haven't replied to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use `replace` to change value by regex.

Try this `urlGenerator` function :

```
function urlGenerator(url, field, value) {
    var reg = new RegExp('('+field+'=[^&]*)', "");
    return url.replace(reg, field+'='+value);
}
```

EDIT:

If you wan't a static url in your function :

```
function urlGenerator(field, value) {
    var url = "www.domain.com/?id=10&name=xxx&dob=2018-12-13";
    var reg = new RegExp('('+field+'=[^&]*)', "");
    return url.replace(reg, field+'='+value);
}
```