# Unsplash API triggering download

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, rest

I'm following triggering guidelines in Unsplash documentation. So the endpoint is:

```
GET /photos/:id/download
```

This is the photo's example response:

```
{
  "id": "LBI7cgq3pbM",
  "width": 5245,
  "height": 3497,
  "color": "#60544D",
  "urls": { ... },
  "user": { ... },
  "links": {
    "self": "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/LBI7cgq3pbM",
    "html": "https://unsplash.com/photos/LBI7cgq3pbM",
    "download": "https://unsplash.com/photos/LBI7cgq3pbM/download", // don't use this property
    "download_location": "https://api.unsplash.com/photos/LBI7cgq3pbM/download?ixid=MnwxMTc4ODl8MHwxfHNlYXJjaHwxfHxwdXBweXxlbnwwfHx8fDE2MTc3NTA2MTM" // use this one ;)
  }
}
```

"Be sure to include any query parameters included in the URL (like the ixid)."

So my question is what is value od `ixid=MnwxMTc4ODl8MHwxfHNlYXJjaHwxfHxwdXBweXxlbnwwfHx8fDE2MTc3NTA2MTM` and how to get it?

Comment: You need to parse the `links.download_location` as a URL. [Here is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/how-do-i-parse-a-url-query-parameters-in-javascript) on Stack Overflow for parsing URL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```js
const ixid = new URLSearchParams(
  new URL("https://api.unsplash.com/photos/LBI7cgq3pbM/download?ixid=MnwxMTc4ODl8MHwxfHNlYXJjaHwxfHxwdXBweXxlbnwwfHx8fDE2MTc3NTA2MTM").search
).get("ixid");
console.log(ixid);
```