# Looking for a regex to parse parameters string for JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I cannot find out the regex to get param value from the part of query string:

I need to send parameter name to a method and get parameter value as result for string like
`"p=1&qp=10"`.
I came up with the following:

```
function getParamValue(name) {

  var regex_str = "[&]" + name + "=([^&]*)";

  var regex = new RegExp(regex_str);

  var results = regex.exec(my_query_string);
  // check if result found and return results[1]

}
```

My regex_str now doesn't work if `name = 'p'`. if I change `regex_str` to

```
var regex_str = name + "=([^&]*)";
```

it can return value of param `'qp'` for param `name = 'p'`

Can you help me with regex to search the beginning of param name from right after `'&'` OR from the beginning of a string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use the get parameter of the url in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827368/use-the-get-parameter-of-the-url-in-javascript) and [many other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+get+parameter+from+query).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work, depending on if you have separated the parameter part.

```
var regex_str = "(?:^|\&)" + name + "=([^&]*)";
or
var regex_str = "(?:\&|\?)" + name + "=([^&]*)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `split` will work better here:

```
var paramsMap = {};
var params = string.split("&");
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; ++i) {
    var keyValue = params[i].split("=", 2);
    paramsMap[keyValue[0]] = keyValue[1];
}
```

If you desperately want to use a regex, you need to use the `g` flag and the `exec` method. Something along the lines of

```
var regex = /([^=]+)=([^&]+)&?/g;
var paramsMap = {};
while (true) {
    var match = regex.exec(input);
    if (!match)
        break;
    paramsMap[match[1]] = match[2];
}
```

Please note that since the `regex` object becomes stateful, you either need to reset its `lastIndex` property before running another extraction loop or use a new `RegExp` instance.

Comment: I agree but I am also interested in the solution for educational reason :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your regex string to the following:

```
//pass the query string and the name of the parameter's value you want to retrieve
function getParamValue(my_query_string , name)
{
    var regex_str = "(?:^|\&)" + name + "\=([^&]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regex_str);
    var results = regex.exec(my_query_string); 
    try
    {
        if(results[1] != '')
        {
            return results[1];
        }
    }
    catch(err){};
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `[\?\&]?` will be ignored, allowing name to be preceeded with anything. `\=(((?!\&).)*)` is equivalent to and more efficient as `([^&]*)`