# Set iFrame src from window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Using jQuery or javascript, I have fumbled with this and finally give in.

How can I set an iframe src like this:

1. If the window URL contains a parameter starting with "?sku="
2. Cache entire parameter from ? to end (?sku=T235N&addressline=90803&form=product_search)
3. Change iframe src from /index.html to /default.html + parameter?

   Change iframe src="/index.html
    to src="/default.html?sku=T235N&addressline=90803&form=product_search"

http://jsfiddle.net/Digitalctn/rUnQd/

Thank you a ton!!!!

Comment: Use `console.log(window.location)` in Firebug or Chrome Console and take a look at what's in that object. Then use `window.addEventListener`/`window.attachEvent` to listen to page load and set the `iframe`'s `src` property with what you find useful in the `location` object.

Comment: Jared thank you but I'm a jQuery rookie. How do I code that?

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rUnQd/6/ Note, it won't do anything since there's no `sku` to be found. But that should work in practice.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what have you tried with javascript on the above solution, even in fiddle i couldnt see any javascript

i would recommend you to go through the below posts

[Using the GET parameter of a URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827368/use-the-get-parameter-of-the-url-in-javascript)

the above post will help get the parameter "sku"

now if you have any value in the same you can set the iframe src by

```
document.getElementById("iframeid").src = "default.html?sku="+sku
```

Comment: that worked. It allowed me to target an iframe location from a form submit

Answer (score 1):

First, give your `iframe` an `id` so we can `getElementById`:

```
<iframe src="http://hosted.where2getit.com/asics/index.html" id="sku_frame"
```

Then, setup a script to run on page load, detect if there's an `sku=` key in the `location.search` string, and grab the `iframe` reference and modify it's `el.src`:

```
(function load(){

    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('load', run);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onload', run);
    }

    function run() {
        var hassku = !!(location.search.indexOf('sku=') + 1);

        if (hassku) {
            document.getElementById('sku_frame').src = '/default.html' + location.search;
        }
    }

})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rUnQd/6/

Comment: Jared thank you. If I pass the param to the fiddle url it doesn't update the iframe source.  http://jsfiddle.net/rUnQd/6/?sku=T235N&addressline=90803&form=product_search

Comment: There's not really a simple way to get jsFiddle to mock that; the `window` it's actually referencing is the `iframe` to the bottom, right, where the content displays. Which is not that simple to modify without `jsFiddle` freaking out. Also, note you're using a base relative URL, e.g., `/default.html`. You would need to compensate for that on jsFiddle, as well, since it will point to `http://fiddle.jshell.net` instead.

Comment: Jared, thank you again. I set that off jsFiddle but still not working - maybe I missed something here? http://www.digitalctn.com/Asicslocator/?sku=T235N&addressline=90803&form=product_search/

Comment: You're using an XHTML DOCTYPE, which means your `script` tags need to be `<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[...code...//]]></script>`.  Unless you have a *good* reason for using XHTML (other than "I use it to check for errors in markup"), do not use XHTML; use HTML5, which would be `<!doctype html>`. If you open that page with a `console` open, you'll see it's throwing an illegal character error on the space at the very end of the code block.

Comment: Apparently, there was some junk at the end of the block too (maybe an encoding error). Anyhow, you don't need to put the `?` on `default.html` either; `location.search` already has it. Here it is "working" (the url loads an empty response). However, I show you the URL in the `IFRAME src`, and color the border `blue` so you can tell something's happened. http://jfcoder.com/t/Fiddle.html?sku=T235N&addressline=90803&form=product_search/ Here it is not working: http://jfcoder.com/t/Fiddle.html?uks=T235N&addressline=90803&form=product_search/

Comment: Ok, I see; the `iframe` is a valid XHTML application. That doesn't mean the page the parent document needs to be, but it works either way. I put the XHTML DOCTYPE back.

Answer (score 0):

Just find the '?' in window location and set the src:

```
var url = window.location;
var pos = url.indexOf('?');
var query = url.substring(0,pos+1);
```

then set it with JQuery:

```
$('iframe').attr('src','/default.html?'+query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe id="changeIframe" src="http://hosted.where2getit.com/asics/index.html" frameborder="1" width="920" height="635" scrolling="no"></iframe> 

document.getElementByid("changeIframe").src='http://hosted.where2getit.com/asics//default.html?sku=T235N&addressline=90803&form=product_search"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this

```
$(function () {
    var url = parseUrl(window.location.pathname).search;
    if (url.match("sku").length > 0) {
        $('#iframe1').attr('src', '/default.html' + url);
    }
});

function parseUrl(url) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    return a;
}
```

And the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muthusamy/rUnQd/12/)