# how to get HTTP GET request value using javascript

Tags: javascript, get

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get query string values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

how can I get the HTTP GET request using javascript?

for example if I have access `www.sample.com/div/a/dev.php?name=sample`

how can I get the GET request of `name=sample` and the value if `name` which is `sample`?

Comment: please clarify your question if possible

Comment: You mean something like this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827368/use-the-get-parameter-of-the-url-in-javascript

Comment: Here you have a function that checks if vairable set in URL but it parse all the URI. You can use this function and update it for your needs.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491209/jquery-event-handler-if-get-is-set/22491912#22491912

Comment: This question has also been asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448545/how-to-retrieve-get-parameters-from-javascript and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) object might come useful here:

```
var parameter = window.location.search.replace( "?", "" ); // will return the GET parameter 

var values = parameter.split("=");

console.log(values); // will return and array as ["name", "sample"]
```

Comment: will return a string of all query string parameters, anchors, and anything else after the question mark.

Comment: and you can split the string from '=', and you will get the parameter and the value

Comment: Did you test this? `parameter = "foo=bar&blah=123"`, result `["foo", "bar&blah", "123"]`

Answer (score 3):

```
Here is a fast way to get an object similar to the PHP $_GET array:

function get_query(){
    var url = location.href;
    var qs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0, result = {}; i < qs.length; i++){
        qs[i] = qs[i].split('=');
        result[qs[i][0]] = qs[i][1];
    }
    return result;
}
Usage:

var $_GET = get_query();
For the query string x=5&y&z=hello&x=6 this returns the object:

{
  x: "6",
  y: undefined,
  z: "hello"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `location.href` to fetch the full URL and then extract the values using `split`

Answer (score 0):

Build the URL string and use jQuery [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)