# How to get access token from the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, uri

I'm getting this URL after I'm authenticated to Google

```
http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google#access_token=ya29.5HxuYol1Io8JLeGePDznbfkkwu_PC4uodKwG8_1clFYAn9AgdOV1WGpOTNQP3s76HAsn7Y4zWw&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

How to get `access_token` value from this url?

I tried solutions in following urls, none of them are working

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

[How to get the value from the GET parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter)

[Using the GET parameter of a URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827368/using-the-get-parameter-of-a-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using modern ways, there are better, more reliable ways to get access token field:

```
var urlString = 'http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google#access_token=ya29.5HxuYol1Io8JLeGePDznbfkkwu_PC4uodKwG8_1clFYAn9AgdOV1WGpOTNQP3s76HAsn7Y4zWw&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600';

var url = new URL(urlString);
// OR: If you want to use the current page's URL
var url = window.location;

var access_token = new URLSearchParams(url.search).get('access_token');
```

You can also see how this approach makes it easy to get the other parameters in addition.  This `URLSearchParams` approach is supported by all browsers except old instances of IE.

---

If the above doesn't work (didn't for me) just add 'hash' to `window.location`, this is also single line code

```
var access_token = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash).get('access_token');
```

#### Old Answer:

I like RegEx so here's a RegEx answer:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google#access_token=ya29.5HxuYol1Io8JLeGePDznbfkkwu_PC4uodKwG8_1clFYAn9AgdOV1WGpOTNQP3s76HAsn7Y4zWw&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600',
    access_token = url.match(/\#(?:access_token)\=([\S\s]*?)\&/)[1];
```

`access_token` is:

> `ya29.5HxuYol1Io8JLeGePDznbfkkwu_PC4uodKwG8_1clFYAn9AgdOV1WGpOTNQP3s76HAsn7Y4zWw`

*(Directly from the console)*

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o7sjp6ju/)

Comment: I love Regex too! Nice answer

Comment: how do you get the token_type and the other url parameters?

Answer (score 8):

Make use of the URL class in JS:

```js
var token = new URL("http://localhost:3000/_oauth/google#access_token=ya29.5HxuYol1Io8JLeGePDznbfkkwu_PC4uodKwG8_1clFYAn9AgdOV1WGpOTNQP3s76HAsn7Y4zWw&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600").hash.split('&').filter(function(el) { if(el.match('access_token') !== null) return true; })[0].split('=')[1];

alert(token);
```

Comment: seems to include `&token_type` at the end

Comment: Fixed it. Added in a little bit of regex spice and some peppery smooth filtering

Comment: Instead of `new URL(...)`, can use `document.location` as well in above expression.