# How to get facebook user access token without using sdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to get facebook user access token using Login Dialog and without using Javascript SDK.

```
fetch(`https://www.facebook.com/v2.12/dialog/oauth?
client_id=APP_ID
&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
&scope=manage_pages,publish_pages
&response_type=token`, {
mode: 'no-cors',
});
```

It redirects to https://www.facebook.com/login.php and has `cancel_url` param:

```
cancel_url: "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied#_=_"
```

But I didn't cancelled login, no login window at all.
Why this error happens and how to fix it?

Comment: you can´t just do an ajax call to the login dialog...what exactly are you trying to achieve? why not just use the official sdk and FB.login or the login button?

Comment: @luschn I only need to get user access token. don't want to include sdk that has lots of things. So it is not possible to do without sdk?

Comment: of course it´s possible, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#login

> Your app must initiate a redirect to an endpoint which will display the login dialog...

You have to redirect to that URL, instead of trying to use it with an AJAX call. Also, make sure you are using a valid App ID (`client_id=APP_ID`).

Comment: how can I get location response header after redirect? it contains token

Comment: you mean, the fragment? there are many tutorials for this, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934606/how-to-get-access-token-from-the-url

Comment: also, check out the links in my answer and search for "Handling Login Dialog Response". i suggest you read the whole page, if you really want to implement manual login.

Comment: no, not parsing, I mean I need to get response headers after redirect. I use window.location.href.

Comment: exactly, just take a look at the link in my answer, it explains how to handle the response.