# How do I create a prev/next function for a one page display site?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm looking to create a function to display prev-next buttons on the header of a one page site.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `issue` ORDER BY `issue_no` DESC LIMIT 1";
```

The content for the entire site comes off a primary key in the database titled "issue_no" everything inside issue_no is the content to be displayed on the one page.

```
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<article id='date_published'><p>Date published:&nbsp;" . $row['date_published'] . "</p></article>";
        echo "<article id='article_head'>" . $row['article_head'] . "</article>";
        echo "<article id='article_body'>" . $row['article_body'] . "</article>";
        echo "<article id='vidpicks_embed'>" . $row['vidpick'] . "</article>";
        echo "<article id='quote_body'>" . $row['quote_body'] . "&mdash;</article>";
        echo "<article id='quote_auth'>" . $row['quote_auth'] . "</article>";
        echo "<article id='wotd_body'>" . $row['wotd_body'] . "</article>";
        echo "<article id='wotd_desc'>" . $row['wotd_desc'] . "</article>";     
    }
}
```

This is displayed on index.php

Currently, it displays the latest issue pending on the publish date, but I would like to add the function to go back to previous and next editions.

On top of this, I'd like to rollout all issues inside a dropdown select menu that allows you to select say "Issue 23" and it would link you through to the appropriate content contained in that issue.

Also - how would I go about making sure these each have clean URLs?

e.g. http://www.example.com/issue/023

Any help much appreciated.

I've tried reading up on pagination, but I'm finding it a little complicated to wrap my head around this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Felixheimer! Unfortunately your question is too broad for this site. We'll be happy to help you with the specific problems you encounter while programming your stuff, but please before read careful “[How do ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)” for more information.

Comment: Can you show that what you tried?

Comment: There's also a way to do this is to use jQuery UI/Mobile.

Comment: I've added the code above if that helps any - that's displayed on index.php - so it's basically having to select specific issues or determining which issue we're on and using the appropriate prev/next to get to the right one.

Comment: Apologies - should have added the code! Makes way more sense hopefully :)

Comment: I am currently making a new code, slightly before you posted the code.
:( Making a new code again. ha

Comment: @AnthonyLaw see [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35293855/revisions)

Comment: Never had any code in the original.

Answer (score 0):

These code I haven't tested, not stable at all. You have to optimize it.

***Function to get data***

In PHP:

```
<?php
$issueno = $_GET["issueno"];
if($issueno == null){
$issueno = 0;
}
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM `issue` ORDER BY `issue_no` DESC LIMIT " + $issueno + ",1";
if($row = mysqli->query($query, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT))
{
/* row is the row selected */
        echo "<article id='date_published'><p>Date published:&nbsp;" . $row['date_published'] . "</p></article>";
    echo "<article id='article_head'>" . $row['article_head'] . "</article>";
    echo "<article id='article_body'>" . $row['article_body'] . "</article>";
    echo "<article id='vidpicks_embed'>" . $row['vidpick'] . "</article>";
    echo "<article id='quote_body'>" . $row['quote_body'] . "&mdash;</article>";
    echo "<article id='quote_auth'>" . $row['quote_auth'] . "</article>";
    echo "<article id='wotd_body'>" . $row['wotd_body'] . "</article>";
    echo "<article id='wotd_desc'>" . $row['wotd_desc'] . "</article>";
}else{
echo "It does not exist";
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

***NEXT***

In Javascript, by redirecting with a issueno parameter

```
function next(){
var currentissueno = getQueryVariable("issueno");
if (currentissueno == null){
//Added 1 here as NEXT
currentissueno = 0;
}
//Maximum issues No. OutOfBounds not handled... I have to sleep now
currentissueno++;
//Redirect (should use window.location.href instead of static url)
//window.location = window.location.href + "?issueno=" + currentissueno; 
window.location = "http://www.example.com/index.php?issueno=" + currentissueno; 
}
```

***PREVIOUS***

In Javascript, by redirecting with a issueno parameter

```
function prev(){
var currentissueno = getQueryVariable("issueno");
if (currentissueno == null){
alert("The last previous page");
return;
}
currentissueno--;
//Redirect (should use window.location.href instead of static url)
//window.location = window.location.href + "?issueno=" + currentissueno; 
window.location = "http://www.example.com/index.php?issueno=" + currentissueno; 
}
```

***Function to GET url parameter***

Required. From [Using the GET parameter of a URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827368/using-the-get-parameter-of-a-url-in-javascript)

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh right! I see what you're doing... is it possible to this entirely in php or is javascript needed?

Also - how would I go about making the URLs in this format http://www.example.com/issue/023 - is that .htaccess?

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @Felixheimer Are you going to make yourself a blog?

Comment: @Felixheimer You have to modify settings in Apache or IIS. Or by generating new files by PHP

Comment: @Felixheimer Note fusion3k 's answer, which would be better than mine

Answer (score 0):

You say:

> On top of this, I'd like to rollout all issues inside a dropdown select menu that allows you to select say "Issue 23" and it would link you through to the appropriate content contained in that issue.

Assuming (for example) an URL like “http://www.example.com/issue.php?issue=23” (for now postponed the ‘clean’ URL question) you can resolve all questions in this way:

```
$issueId = $_GET['issue'];

/* 01: Retrieve ALL id */
$result = $con->query( "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( `issue_no` ORDER BY `issue_no` DESC ) FROM `issue`" );
$allId = explode( ',', $result->fetch( PDO::FETCH_NUM )[0] );

/* 02: Check if $issueId exists and set previous/next id */
$prev = $next = False;
$found = array_search( $key, $allId );
if( $found === False )         $found = count( $allId )-1;
if( $found > 0 )               $prev = $allId[$found-1];
if( $found < count($allId)-1 ) $next = $allId[$found+1];

/* 03: Retrieve current issue: */
$result = $con->query( "SELECT * FROM `issue` WHERE `issue_no` = '{$allId[$found]}'" );
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

/* 04: Output previous/next page link: */
if( $prev !== False ) echo "<a href=\"?issue=$prev\">Prev Page</a>";
else                  echo "<span class=\"inactive\">Prev Page</span>";
if( $next !== False ) echo "<a href=\"?issue=$next\">Next Page</a>";
else                  echo "<span class=\"inactive\">Next Page</span>";

// Your code from here
```

Code above is only as example. By this way, all `issue_no` are stored in `$allId` variable, so you can easy implement also the *dropdown menu*. The `issue_no` fields are retrieved in descending order, if you prefer ascending you can change first query (#01) in `ORDER BY issue_no ASC`.

Note that if the user don't ask for any specific issue (i.e. calling http://www.example.com/issue.php), the current issue is set to first array value of `$allId` (#02): if you prefer to produce an alert like “This issue doesn't exists” you have to modify the script in this way:

```
$found = array_search( $key, $allId );
if( $found === False )
{
    // Your error routine here
}
else
{
    if( $found > 0 ) $prev = $allId[$found-1];
    (...)
}
```

In the output of previous/next page URLs (#04), I use a basic `<a href>` tag, but you can use buttons.

#### Clean URLs

I strongly recommend to produce first a full working code ignoring the ‘clean’ URL question. Then, all you will need to change will be only one row.

By the way, to activate clean urls, you have to modify the *.htaccess* file of your site in a way like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^issue/.*$ /issue.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

then, in your `issue.php` script, you have to change `$issueId = $_GET['issue'];` with:

```
$issueId = array_pop( explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) );
```

This *RewriteRule* is only an example, actually I think you are interested in clean URLs for all your site, so the best solution can be to redirect all incoming URLs to a `redirect.php` that process the `REQUEST_URI` and include appropriate page or echoes ‘Not Found’ message.

[Here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-basic-examples.html) you can find more about basics on *RewriteRule*